# Can't get user profile for user who write in Messenger

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I implemented integration with Facebook Messenger according to the documentation. User login via Login via Facebook for companies. I get the user token and then I get page access token. I register subscriptions via "https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/{appId}/subscriptions" for the application and "https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/{pageId}/subscribed_apps" for pages. All calls return success. The webhook is registered correctly.
When a user writes to a Messenger page, I receive a webhook call, but when I make a request to get the profile of the user who wrote the message, I do not receive any data. I make a request with the fields “id, first_name, last_name, picture”, and I only get a picture.
How to get the profile data of the user who wrote the message?
If I register the page manually through the developer console and use the access token from the console, then I receive the user profile data correctly.

Comment: _"and use the access token from the console"_ - and what access token are you using in the other case? Sounds like they probably don't both encompass the same set of permissions, so debug them to verify that first of all.

Comment: I use page access token that I get from user profile:
https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/{userId}
with fields: 'id,accounts{id,name,access_token}'
I got the list of all accessible pages with their page access token.